# use jQuery to toggle marginLeft?

Tags: jquery

I've got a menu that is 100% width, then I'm checking the width and throwing it off screen by that amount. What I'd like to achieve is a toggle marginLeft effect.

I have this, which obviously doesn't slide back in. I'm working in em's.

```
    var em = $(window).width() / parseFloat($("body").css("font-size"));
    emEm = em+'em'; //change px to em and add em unit i.e. XXem

    $('nav').width(emEm); //makes nav full width in em's
    $('nav').css('margin-left','-'+emEm); //throws nav off screen

    $('.menu').click(function() {
        $('nav').animate({
            marginLeft: '0' //bring nav back on screen
        }, 300);
    });
```

Is there a way to toggle the menu click function?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `-100%` and `0` respectively:

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/5xrGu/

```
$('nav').animate({
    marginLeft: '-100%'
}, 300);
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks! It must be me, as it's fine on your fiddle, but for some reason the first click does nothing then following clicks slide out and in perfectly. Will post code shortly...

Comment: Changing the position of closed=!closed seems to work. Moved it to before the animate. Just for my knowledge, what does closed=!closed actually do?

Comment: @Geoff - That line is for flipping the state.

Answer (score 0):

Edited the post. Look at this. I know it can be done faster and shorter, but for now this will work.

```
<script>
    var clicked = false,
        margin_value;

    $('#on-click-id').click(function(){
        $('nav').stop(); //Stop the animation on each click
        if(clicked == false){
            margin_value = '+=10px';
            //Set clicked to true so the next click will be decreasing the margin
            clicked == true;
        } else if (clicked == false){
            margin_value = '-=10px';
            //Set clicked to false so the next click will be increasing the margin
            clicked = false;
        }

        $('nav').animate({
            marginLeft: margin_value //bring nav back on screen
        }, 300);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: not quite - it slides in an out but also hides. If there was a way to stop it hiding this would be great

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.menu').click(function() {
$('nav').toggle(function() {
$('nav').animate({marginLeft: "0"}, 300},
function() {
$('nav').animate({marginLeft: "100%"}, 300});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the toggle seems to be causing the menu to hide as well as animate...

Comment: Can you throw it all together for me in a jfiddle with my code added in and I'll fix it for you.