# Adjusting Margin Left With JQuery Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
function change_width() {
    $('#cont').toggle(function(){
        $('#cont').animate({marginLeft:'0%'});
    },function(){
        $('#cont').animate({marginLeft:'18.4%'});
    });
}
```

I have the following code here, and it should work but it doesn't. Instead it's affecting the `display` attribute, making it display: none. Why is it doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use jQuery to toggle marginLeft?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329361/use-jquery-to-toggle-marginleft)

Comment: `toggle(function,function)` is deprecated http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: @RamSegev No. I already know what to do it's just it doesn't do it.

Comment: @charlietfl that doesn't help my current issue

Comment: Sure it does. If you are using a version > 1.8 `toggle()` is only for display

Comment: If you know what to do, where's the question?

Comment: @charlietfl my bad. Is there any other methods to doing something like this without reverting to an older JQuery version?

Comment: Why not toggle a class also then check if that class exists or not

Comment: @charlietfl how do i do that if i cant use `toggle()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `toggle(function, function)` is deprecated a simple way is toggle a class and check for that class

```
function change_width() {
  var $cont = $('#cont');       

  $cont.animate({
    marginLeft: $cont.hasClass('inset') ? '0%' : '18.4%'
  }).toggleClass('inset');

}
```